# Entity Framework Children Can Not Be Evaluated

Tags: c#, entity-framework

So I am using the entity framework rather successfully, but have been working on speed up the application runtime.  As I loop over records, I check to see if the record already exists and I found that calling the dbcontext for every record to check for a duplicate wastes a lot of time compared to getting all the records in memory, and checking against that.  This is what I have been trying to do.

Is there any reason I can store these in an IEnumerable?

Entity Framework is pretty amazing, but it is maddeningly slow and I am not even talking about calling .SaveChanges() with large sets to update/insert.  It seems that the dbContext only gets records when it needs it, so it makes numerous calls to the database instead of gathering the set in memory, and checking against that to save on wasted db calls.

```
    IEnumerable<pPeople> people;
    IEnumerable<pPeople_Address> peopleAddress;
    IEnumerable<pPeople_ContactNumbers> peopleNumbers;
    IEnumerable<pPeople_EMail> peopleEmails;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (CRMEntities crm = new CRMEntities())
        {
            people = crm.pPeoples.Where(p => p.import_num == ImportNumber).Select(p => p).AsEnumerable();
            peopleAddress = crm.pPeople_Address.Where(a => a.import_num == ImportNumber).Select(a => a).AsEnumerable();
            peopleNumbers = crm.pPeople_ContactNumbers.Where(n => n.import_num == ImportNumber).Select(n => n).AsEnumerable();
            peopleEmails = crm.pPeople_EMail.Where(em => em.import_num == ImportNumber).Select(em => em).AsEnumerable();

        }
    }
```

I am currently trying to call methods such as:  The first one is what I currently use, the second one is what I want to use.

```
pPeople_Address recordExists = crm.pPeoples.Select(p => p.pPeople_Address.Where(a => a.People_ID == person.ID && a.Address1 == contactAddress.LINE1).FirstOrDefault()).FirstOrDefault();
pPeople_Address recordExists = peopleAddress.Where(a => a.People_ID == person.ID && a.Address1 == contactAddress.LINE1).FirstOrDefault();
```

**Solution:**
I needed to use .ToList() to have my entities loaded immediately instead of lazily.

Here is what my single entity call looks like now:

```
people = crm.pPeoples.Where(p => p.import_num == ImportNumber).Select(p => p).AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

And calls later on take the form of:

```
pPeople_Address recordExists = people.Select(p => p.pPeople_Address.Where(a => a.People_ID == person.ID && a.Address1 == contactAddress.LINE1).FirstOrDefault()).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: There are probably better ways to check if something exists than getting the whole entity from the database. Also, unless you're fetching records one-by-one, I don't think the overhead of a database call is making as much of an impact as the data transfer and creating entities. In your case there should only be 4.

Comment: If you look at the second part of the code I posted, If I remove either of those statements, my entire solution runs in less than a minute.  With those calls, it takes 45 minutes or so.  Before using EF I would cache results in memory based on import number (only loading the data that is relevant) then check against that while running.  Doing that saves a LARGE amount of time.  There is only one database call getting the information.  What is slowing this application down is single database calls within my methods, hence why I want to cache the relevant data in memory from the start.

Comment: I plan on using EF to track all changes and then change the underlying SQL insert/updates to bulk insert and update using stored procedures.  My goal is the have EF track changes to the entities, provide built in transactions and rollbacks, copying of objects, etc...  I can accomplish this same code using datasets no problem, but I will no longer have any of the nice features of EF.

Comment: That's a bizarre way of using EF. Why doesn't `pPeople` have a property that points to `pPeople_Address`? (I'm not sure that's the problem, but it does show some misunderstanding of what EF is supposed to do.) Also what's `person`? Is it a typo for `p`?

Comment: My greater point is that re-querying the data on demand should not have that much performance impact unless you're doing it really, really excessively. (And that's not EF making wasted database calls, but you.) In which case caching would be a good idea, but it's really hard to tell from just one event handler what is taking up that much time - I doubt either of the problematic statements you added in your edit takes up those 45 minutes on its own.

Comment: Well pPeople does point to pPeople_Address.  All of these tables are nested in pPeople.  So I may be calling them incorrectly in my initial calls.  I have done crm.pPeoples.Where(p => p.pPeople_Address.Where(logic here)).Select(p => p);

Comment: I just realized what you guys are all talking about.  I only need the original people = .... call.  All the objects nested are returned in that results set.  Ok, time to change the code.

Comment: They're not *exactly* returned immediately. To avoid excessively loading data, EF loads "child" entities through to-many relationships on-demand. You can and should preload them explicitly in the same call using `.Include()`. (This is in fact a common performance issue - the so-called "N+1 selects problem", and might actually be happening somewhere in your case now that I remembered it.) So to fetch all people with their addresses, you would use for example `db.People.Include(p => p.Addresses).ToList()`.

Comment: Thanks millimoose, that was exactly what I needed.  Thanks for all the other advice too!  I was doing some weird things with EF and wasn't even realizing it.  I seem to have my code down to around 10 minutes (based on current run time estimation).  Time to find more ways to improve the speed of EF.  I know I can get this down to 2 minutes or less (running over 20k+ records) before .SaveChanges() is called.

Comment: (Another option is never returning entities from your data access layer, but instead returning DTOs that are similar in structure to your entities but tailored to what the above layer needs. This involves a fair amount of annoying boilerplate code and potentially very very ugly final `.Select()` expressions, but it's easier to prevent extra DB calls that way.)